# CombiningPDF's on filename

Tags: python

Hello I wrote this code to extract a list of **PDF** names.it** then compares to the input of where the **PDF** data is stored.The current code merges everything in that folder that is in the pdf data i commented out the part where it checks if the filename "starts with" because it's only then merges one of the documents and not all that are specified.

```
import json
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os

input = 'pdfdata'  
list = os.listdir(input)

with open('pdf.json','r') as jsonfile:

    jason_info =json.load(jsonfile)
    json_data = [jason_info]

for item in json_data:
   for data_item in item['info']:
       jobjects = (data_item.values())#return only values
       informa = ''.join(ll)#string
   
       filemerger = PdfFileMerger()
       for file in dlist: 
       # if file.startswith(informa):           
               
            filemerger.append(file)
            filemerger.write("combinedpdfs.pdf")
         
 filemerger.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want it to?

```
filemerger = PdfFileMerger()

for item in json_data:
    for dicitonary in item['documents']:  # retrieve key & value
        for pdf in dictionary.values():
            if pdf in dlist:
                filemerger.append(pdf)
            else:
                raise ValueError(f'Pdf file {pdf} missing!')

filemerger.write("combinedpdfs.pdf")
filemerger.close()
```

I moved the `filemerger` line out of the for block as otherwise you're constantly resetting it. I also removed the for loop which goes through `dlist` as you can just check if the pdf file is in dlist.

Comment: yes thank you soo much appreciate it ,is it possible you can add on to your code to make it fail if one of the values is not found in the directory.i dont want it to merge if theres a missing file

Comment: i mean to say if a file listed in the json is not available

Comment: There you go, ideally it would be a custom error but if you just want to stop the program dead in its tracks that should do fine